Specify no heading on ORG mode table
I have the following table, with six sections. When I export it, it looks fine except that the export assumes that the first section is headings, but there is no heading on my table. How can I specify this to get the export right? Top priority is HTML export, but it would be nice if it works across target formats.
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|
| *Artikel*:                                          |      |
| _id_, rubrik, text, tid                             | 1p   |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|
| *Skribent*:                                         |      |
| _pnr_, namn, beskrivning                            | 1p   |
| FK: bylinebild (till Bild)                          | 1.5p |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|
| *Bild*:                                             |      |
| _url_, beskrivning                                  | 1p   |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|
| *Kommentar*:                                        |      |
| _id_, text, signatur                                | 1p   |
| FK: artikel                                         | 1.5p |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|
| *Artikelbild* (sambandstabell):                     |      |
| FK: _bild_url_ (till Bild), _art_id_ (till Artikel) | 2p   |
| alt_text, position                                  | 1p   |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|
| *Skriven_av* (sambandstabell):                      |      |
| FK: _art_id_ (till Artikel), _pnr_ (till Skribent)  | 2p   |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|


You could consider to use some custom styles in order to customize the output that you're getting, and style the headers. Here is an example:
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">
#+HTML_HEAD: .my-table thead tr th.org-left { text-align: left; }
#+HTML_HEAD: .my-table thead tr:nth-child(2) th.org-left { font-weight: normal; }
#+HTML_HEAD: </style>
#+ATTR_HTML: :class my-table
| *Artikel*:                                          |      |
| _id_, rubrik, text, tid                             | 1p   |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|
| *Skribent*:                                         |      |
| _pnr_, namn, beskrivning                            | 1p   |
| FK: bylinebild (till Bild)                          | 1.5p |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|
| *Bild*:                                             |      |
| _url_, beskrivning                                  | 1p   |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|
| *Kommentar*:                                        |      |
| _id_, text, signatur                                | 1p   |
| FK: artikel                                         | 1.5p |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|
| *Artikelbild* (sambandstabell):                     |      |
| FK: _bild_url_ (till Bild), _art_id_ (till Artikel) | 2p   |
| alt_text, position                                  | 1p   |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|
| *Skriven_av* (sambandstabell):                      |      |
| FK: _art_id_ (till Artikel), _pnr_ (till Skribent)  | 2p   |
|-----------------------------------------------------+------|

Another approach could be to customize this variable: org-html-table-header-tags so that you don't get a th element but replace it with a td:
(setq org-html-table-header-tags '("<td scope=\"%s\"%s>" . "</td>"))


Can you support the statement that it would be illegal for an html table to not have any th or thead? I cannot find any such requirement. And I am certain that a table in LaTeX doesn’t have to have headings. It seems strange that ORG mode would always assume that the top section is heading.

The table would result in a violation of WCAG requirements, you can read about it here https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/info-and-relationships

I have updated the answer as it was invalid what I first said. It would be a violation but of accessibility rules, not the markup itself.

I upvoted your answer since it gives some information about this, but it’s not the answer to my question. It seems to imply that the answer is: “ORG mode assumes that a table always has a heading section and this cannot be configured away”, but this seems strange to me.
